# Relationship of Hurdy-Gurdy and Organ?

Tags: medieval

Just wondering why this is entitled "Hurdy-Gurdy With Organ". Is it just a Hurdy-Gurdy alone? If so why would it say "With Organ"? It sounds like a riff on G natural minor. I think there's a drone on G. I feel like a snake charmed by this.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for Music Fans.

Comment: @guidot I thought the organ was part of the hurdy gurdy or something. I mean, maybe it makes the same type of sound as an organ or something. So this is a question about the instrument itself not a music fan question. does that mean there's just a backing track of an organ. not sure about that.

Comment: Yes, there is just a non-visible organ involved. The hurdy-gurdy is pretty standard, and there are simply no fingers or arms left, which the player could use for the organ-part. If you check, that the same player offers a video with hurdy-gurdy, organ and drums, you wouldn't assume the drum part was also built-in...

Answer (score 5):

There is definitely an organ involved, since full chords can be heard and the color of tone also does not match a hurdy-gurdy.

It is true, that a hurdy-gurdy has drone strings by itself (the 3 on each side), which can be disabled by putting them apart from the wheel, but they are far weaker than the organ here.

Comment: Not just that, but the background drone keeps going unchanged even while the hurdy gurdy player is repeatedly reversing the direction of the wheel.

Comment: I wonder why this answer isn't marked as "accepted". Sour grapes perhaps?